# How to get an object from an json array of objects based on a value inside an object in python?

Tags: python, arrays, json, object, find

I have a json array of objects that looks like this:

```
{
    "testcases": {
        "testcase": {
            "custom-fields": {
                "custom-field": [{
                    "@id": "testCaseID",
                    "@content": "shotwell15"
                }, {
                    "#text": "-",
                    "@id": "casecomponent"
                }, {
                    "#text": "critical",
                    "@id": "caseimportance"
                }]
            },
            "title": "Shotwell 15"
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to use python and obtain the object from within the `custom-field` array based on the "value" of the `@id` like this:

finding the object:

```
{
   "#text": "critical",
   "@id": "caseimportance"
}
```

based on the value "caseimportance"

I tried to use filter, but that didn't seem to work. I think it shouldn't be this hard. something that is so simple to do in javascript or ruby. In ruby I could just use the .select method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python you can use [list comprehension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension) similar to Ruby's select:

```
custom_fields = data["testcases"]["testcase"]["custom-fields"]["custom-field"]
filtered = [f for f in custom_fields if f["@id"] == "caseimportance"]
```

Python also has a filter that is more directly comparable to Ruby's select:

Python 2:

```
filtered = filter(lambda f: (f["@id"] == "caseimportance"), custom_fields)
```

Python 3:

```
filtered = list(filter(lambda f: (f["@id"] == "caseimportance"), custom_fields))
```

List comprehension is often considered more Pythonic however.

Answer (score 1):

The python module 're' has a search function that you can look into which allows you to filter out the particular word and then use indexes to select other words/text of the json file that are around that word.